# Rules of Big O - Question

Tags: algorithm, big-o, recurrence

If I have the following closed form solution for a recurrence relation, how can I simplify it under big O:

f(n) = 3^n + n.9^n

I would hazard a guess at:

f(n) is a member of O(9^n) -> Am not sure if this right? Could someone please let me know how to simplify the above equation under big O and also state which rule you used...

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation

> If f(x) is a sum of several terms, the one with the largest growth rate is kept, and all others omitted.

So `O(n * 9^n)`, assuming that with `n.9^n` you meant `n * 9^n`.

Comment: n*9^n is not in O(9^n). Proof: If it were, there would be constants c and N0 fulfill that (n*9^n)/(9^n) < c for all n > N0. This is obviously not the case for n > max(c, N0). (n*9^n is in O~(9^n), but O~ is not used all that much really.)

Comment: @Chritopher Creutzig: Excuse me, I'm not that advanced with algorithm runtime notations yet. What would be the correct way to express this in Big-O notation?

Comment: abeln: Thanks, answer edited accordingly. Shouldv'e known, since `O(n*log(n))` is common too.

Answer (score 3):

Simple relations which helps you is:

```
O(1) < O(log(N) < O(N^Epsilon)<O(N)<O(N logN)<O(N^c)<O(c^n)<O(n!)<O(n^n)
```

for c >1 and 0 < Epsilon <1.

See [big O in wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) for better understanding